# Passing object reference to method, must it be static?

Tags: c#

When I'm trying some code to learn about passing a reference of an object to a method, I get an error when I try to remove the static in the methods head. The error message says: An object reference is required for non-static field, method or property...... But isn't there a reference in the parameter already? I have seen code that don't use static, so why does this not work? I know that static is used when method is used from classes that isn't objects. Some explanation is appreciated to understand. Thanks!

```
    // Method
    internal static string ChangeName(Box obj)
    {
        return obj.BoxName;
    }
```

EDIT: I added the whole code. Is the problem that I'm calling from inside the main method that is static?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Box box1, box2;
        box1 = new Box("Nick","R90",1);
        box2 = new Box("Hanna","B27",2);

        Console.WriteLine(ChangeName(box2));
        Console.Read();

    }

    // Methods
    private static string ChangeName(Box obj)
    {
        return obj.BoxName;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what's the code for the non-static method that you tried?  Did you only remove the word `static`?

Comment: The code you showed us is correct. Show other parts of your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A static method is called like this:

```
MyClass.Method(arg);
```

An instance method is called like this:

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.Method(arg);
```

The two are not compatible.

If you want to change the method signature, you also need to change every place where the method is called.

EDIT: You are using the unqualified call. Here are the rules for using an unqualified call.

- A static method can call a static method.
- A static method cannot call an instance method. (This is your problem.)
- An instance method can call a static method.
- An instance method can call an instance method.

This method should really be implemented as an instance method in the Box class. You would then say:

```
Console.WriteLine(box2.ChangeName());
```

If you don't have access to the Box code, and then you could either write an extension method, or keep the method static as per your example.

Comment: OK, but with Console.WriteLine(box2.ChangeName()); then there is no reference bring along to the method!? I get an red line when I use the code?

Comment: Like I said, "This method should really be implemented as an instance method in the Box class."

Answer (score 2):

Probably the error is where you are calling this method; if you are calling from a static method, you must call against an object instance explicitly or call a static method.